# can't build spring-data-graph hello-worlds example

Tags: java, maven, build-error, spring-data-graph

I'm new on maven and new on spring-data-neo4j too.
I've downloaded this [hello-worlds-example](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-data-neo4j/tree/master/spring-data-neo4j-examples/hello-worlds)

I tried to execute the example like described via maven using the command:

```
mvn clean package exec:java
```

I became a lot of errors. I don't find a way to solve the problem even understanding the problem.

```
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Spring Data Neo4j hello-worlds 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ spring-data-neo4j-hello-worlds ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\me\Desktop\SpringSource-spring-data-graph-examples\hello-worlds\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0:compile (default) @ spring-data-neo4j-hello-worlds ---
[ERROR] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfigurerSupport
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.540s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 09 12:26:59 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 12M/108M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0:compile (default) on project spring-data-neo4j-hello-worlds: Compiler errors :
[ERROR] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfigurerSupport
[ERROR] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
[ERROR] [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware
[ERROR] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
[ERROR] [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean
[ERROR] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
[ERROR] [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean
[ERROR] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
[ERROR] [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware
[ERROR] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
[ERROR] [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean
[ERROR] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
[ERROR] [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

My maven is installed correctly:

```
C:\Users\me>mvn -version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_02, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Thanks for your help.

**EDIT (the same with jdk1.6):**

```
C:\Users\me>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 09:44:56+0100)
Maven home: C:\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0_30, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\jre
Default locale: de_DE, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

and:

```
C:\Users\me\Desktop\SpringSource-spring-data-graph-examples\hello-worlds>mvn clean package exec:java 
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Spring Data Neo4j hello-worlds 1.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.4.1:clean (default-clean) @ spring-data-neo4j-hello-worlds ---
[INFO] Deleting C:\Users\me\Desktop\SpringSource-spring-data-graph-examples\hello-worlds\target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0:compile (default) @ spring-data-neo4j-hello-worlds ---
[ERROR] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfigurerSupport
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean
when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
 [Xlint:cantFindType]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 1.528s
[INFO] Finished at: Thu Feb 09 14:56:22 CET 2012
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/78M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:aspectj-maven-plugin:1.0:compile (default) on project spring-data-neo4j-hello-worlds: Compiler errors :
[ERROR] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.wiring.BeanConfigurerSupport
[ERROR] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
[ERROR] [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware
[ERROR] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
[ERROR] [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean
[ERROR] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
[ERROR] [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.DisposableBean
[ERROR] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
[ERROR] [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryAware
[ERROR] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
[ERROR] [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] error can't determine implemented interfaces of missing type org.springframework.beans.factory.InitializingBean
[ERROR] when batch building BuildConfig[null] #Files=7 AopXmls=#0
[ERROR] [Xlint:cantFindType]
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
```

Comment: Could you try to run it with JDK 1.6 ?

Comment: yes i can, see below "EDIT (the same with jdk1.6):"

Comment: The setup Java7, Windows and Maven3 normally works, as I've just learned. Can you try to clean out your maven repository (should be in "Documents and Settngs/.m2/repository") and try again?

Comment: wow, thanks that helped,
I deleted all and start building new,
it runs without errors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can confirm it works with Windows 7, Java 6/7 and Maven 3:

```
C:\Users\lassewesth\IdeaProjects\spring-data-neo4j\spring-data-neo4j-examples\hello-worlds>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 08:44:56+0000)
Maven home: C:\Users\lassewesth\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.6.0_30, vendor: Sun Microsystems Inc.
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.6.0_30\jre
Default locale: en_GB, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

C:\Users\lassewesth\IdeaProjects\spring-data-neo4j\spring-data-neo4j-examples\he
llo-worlds>mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.0.4 (r1232337; 2012-01-17 08:44:56+0000)
Maven home: C:\Users\lassewesth\apache-maven-3.0.4
Java version: 1.7.0_02, vendor: Oracle Corporation
Java home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_02\jre
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 7", version: "6.1", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"
```

Comment: yes its right, @Michael solves the problem, my repository was broken